# WPF button binding

Tags: c#, button, mvvm, binding, label

I've got the application with ListView which I populate with images names, weights, etc. and inside one of the cells should be 2 buttons or labels to user interaction. I've searched and tried what I find on the web, but nothing helps.

```
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Button
                                         Grid.Row="0"
                                         Command="{Binding ShowImageCommand}"
                                         Content="Show">
                                    </Button>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Button Content="Annotate" 
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.ShowImageCommand, 
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                        AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}" />
                                </Grid>
```

Neither option for Annotate button or Show works. I've tried to do it like a label, but also no success.

```
<Label Content="Show" xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity">
                             <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                 <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown" >
                                      <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ShowImageCommand}" />
                                 </i:EventTrigger>
                             </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    </Label>
```

Here is how it looks like in class:

```
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ShowImageCommand = new RelayCommand(ShowImageMethod);
    }

    public ICommand ShowImageCommand { get; set; }

    public void ShowImageMethod()
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged("ShowImageCommand");
        Messenger.Default.Send<NotificationMessage>(new NotificationMessage("It's fine"));
    }
```

I'm new to C# and MVVM pattern, so mostly I just copy-paste code from Stack and trying to make it work. Other buttons on the grid, for example, to add images to ListView are implemented in the same way, but everything works for those. Please give me some hints.

Comment: You have to set the proper `DataContext` to use command binding. Please, share the complete xaml for list view and where is `MainViewModel` set as data context

Comment: Usually you have your ViewModel expose commands. And use button or menu items to represent those commands.

Comment: I do have `<Window x:Class="blabla.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
**here the rest of interface goes**
</Grid>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your viewmodel bind to your view?

```cs
DataContext = new MainViewModel();
```

or

```xml
<Window.DataContext>
  <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Comment: I do have `<Window x:Class="blabla.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
**here the rest of interface goes**
</Grid>`

Answer (score 0):

Like Isaudon said I haven't had

```
DataContext = new MainViewModel();
```

After I added this to MainWindow.xaml.cs is implementation works out:

```
<Button Content="Annotate" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
        Command="{Binding DataContext.ShowImageCommand, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
        AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}" />
```